# copy jekyll remote theme to local

Tags: jekyll

I just noticed that jekyll has all it needs installed locally, but a remote-theme is fetched every time jekyll is started.

I've also seen that people proposed a cache extension which hasn't been merged yet.

So I wonder if it is possible to just clone the remote theme to a certain folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found the solution:

most themes are available also as ruby gems. So instead of specifying a `remote-theme`, I add the corresponding gem to `Gemfile`

```
gem "minimal-mistakes-jekyll"
```

and then reference it in the `_config.yml`

```
theme: minimal-mistakes-jekyll
```